# 405 Get not allowed on apache authentification

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, error-handling, localhost

I am trying to create an Auth Form for my localhost Web Server, and every time I am trying to make it works I am getting this error :

> Method Not Allowed
>   The requested method GET is not allowed for this URL.

Well, I understand that it can't take get into consideration, but I don't really know how to resolve the problem and I don't find any example. Any help will be appreciated.

htaccess :

```
SetHandler form-login-handler
AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://example.com/login.html"
AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "http://example.com/admin/index.html"
AuthFormProvider file
AuthUserFile "conf/passwd"
AuthType form
AuthName /admin
Session On
SessionCookieName session path=/
```

And my html form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" />
    <input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your complete configuration. The examples in the docs has this all wrapped into a `Location` directive, but we currently can't tel if you just left that out of your post, or whether it's actually missing.

Comment: (Not sure if you even _can_ configure this on .htaccess level - the description for directives such as `AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation` specifies the context as `directory`, and the description of that contains the phrasing _"in the server configuration files"_.)